# Can someone help me on this code in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I tried to get value of daily movement price for the past 10 days. I tried to code in pine script, but I am getting error.

Here is my code:

```
NDays = input(title="ADM Length", type=integer, defval=10)        
OPEN=security(tickerid, 'C', close)  
DayC=OPEN[1] 
NDaysDHLAvg=0 
for i=1 
    if i<=NDays 
    h:=i+i

DayH=security(tickerid,"H",high[i])
DayL=security(tickerid,"L",low[i])
NDaysDHLAvg=NDaysDHLAvg+(DayH-DayL) 
NDaysDHLAvg=NDaysDHLAvg/NDays`
```

I am getting an error mentioned below:

> line 8: mismatched input 'end of line without line continuation' expecting 'to'

Comment: I cleaned up your post a bit, but I don't know a lot of pine. My guess, though, is that you need to indent the line `h:=i+i` since it is part of the `if` on the line above.

Comment: Thanks for editing and but still its not working and getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Please post complete, compilable tagged code, including the `version` compiler directive.

This code does what you need:

```
//@version=4
study("ADM")
NDays = input(10, "ADM Length")
avgDMove = sma(high - low, NDays)
plot(security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", avgDMove))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually its a ADM strategy that currently Iam using in Amibroker trading platform. I am planning to migrate myself to TV so I want to create the same  in pine script if you want me to post the entire ADM afl file I will post.

Comment: By "complete compilable code" I meant a code snippet that compiles and runs in Pine, so including the `//version=x` compiler directive telling the compiler what version of Pine you are using, and the `study()` or `strategy()` line, plus any other dependencies the code to be fixed uses. This helps people helping you.

Answer (score 0):

1) `h` is undeclared variable;
2) Tab or 4 spaces are needed before `h:=i+i`

```
for i=1 
    if i<=NDays 
        h:=i+i
```